# Add or remove a class of 'active' within script that already toggles the value of a hidden input with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, button

I have this helpful function below which toggles the value of a hidden input when a button is clicked.  Alternatively, I also need to toggle whether or not said button has a class of "active" applied to it.

HTML:

```
 <input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value1">
 <input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value2">
 <input class="toggleinput" type="hidden" name="value3">

 <ul>
 <li><button class="toggle" name="value1" value="yes">Button 1</button></li>
 <li><button class="toggle" name="value2" value="1">Button 2</button></li>
 <li><button class="toggle" name="value3" value="indeed">Button 3</button></li>
 </ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $('button.toggle').click(function () {
     var value = this.value;
     $('input.toggleinput[name="' + this.name + '"]').val(function () {
         return this.value.length ? '' : value;

     })

      })
```

As I understand it, the script is checking to see if a value is applied to the input and if it is not, then it is applying the value from the button?

What would be the best way to, if the button has not been depressed, to, upon depression, also add the class of 'active' to the button along with the toggle class?  And when the button is pressed again to remove it?

Comment: If anyone has any ideas why this might have been downvoted, please let me know.  If I am posting questions that are not helpful to the community, it would be helpful to know what about the question is a problem.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to see what the code is doing if you change them to `text` inputs )innstead of hidden) as a test:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3938kLof/4/

```
$('button.toggle').click(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('input.toggleinput[name="' + this.name + '"]').val(function () {
        return this.value.length ? '' : value;
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

`$(this)` converts the DOM element pressed (the button, passed as `this`) into a jQuery element. `toggleClass` does what it says on the tin... it toggles the class.